# How to define numbers inside a string to map JSON in Javascript?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

The API has numbers to define each of the data containers, I've tried to use several ways to be able to define these numbers, but without success.

In the image you can see the map `clubes.262` `clubes.264` `clubes.265` `clubes.266` `clubes.275`

[image]

My attempts:

```
var idclub = clubes[i].id;
var idclub = clubes.[i].id;
var idclub = clubes[0][i].id;
var idclub = clubes. + i + .id;
```

The complete script for easy viewing:

```
function MenuMercadoCartola1() {
  var url = 'https://api.cartolafc.globo.com/atletas/mercado';
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  var results = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());

  var clubes = results.clubes;
  var table = [['ID do Clubes','Nome do Clube']];
  for (var i = 0; i < clubes.length; i++) {
    
    var idclub = clubes[i].id;
    var nameclub = clubes[i].nome;
    
    table.push([idclub,nameclub]);
  }

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Menu');
  sheet.getRange(1,1, table.length, table[0].length).setValues(table);
}
```

Comment: Try `+Object.keys(clubes)[i]`

Comment: Actually, I recommend you change your whole loop to `for (var idclub in clubes)` and use `idclub` instead of `i`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you should be using a 'for in' loop.

Your code revised:

```js
for (var idclub in clubes)
{
    idclub = +idclub;
    var nameclub = clubes[idclub].nome;
    
    table.push([idclub, nameclub]);
}
```

Your loop assumes `clubes` is an array however it is an object which means you could have to iterate on it using a `for (var ... in ...)` loop.

Comment: Thanks my friend, you solved the problem perfectly, I'm waiting 2 minutes to put your answer as the solution for the case!

Comment: @BrondbyIF you may want to look at my most recent edit where I added `idclub = +idclub;` to the script as this will make sure it gets inserted into the Google Sheet as a number.